How to print characters on a single line in Python for the tic-tac-toe
I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game and my initial board display should look like this
X | O | X
---------
X | X | O
---------
O | O | X

However my program is printing like this:
 X |
 O |
 X |


 # |
 O |
 X |


 # |
 O |
 X |


How to do I print to achieve the target the metrics.. My program will accept the dimensions and print equal number of rows and columns upto 5x5
Here is my code:
import math

def display_board(board):
    dimensions = ['4', '9','16','25']
    elems = int(len(board))

    if (elems in dimensions):
        print ('COLUMNS AND ROWS ARE EQUAL')
    else:
        print ('COL AND ROWS ARE NOT EQUAL')
   
    rows = int (math.sqrt(elems))
    cols = rows
    

    for r in range (0,rows,1):
        for c in range (0,cols,1):
            print (' ' + board[elems-1] + ' |')
            elems = elems -1    
        print ('\n')


brd = ['X','O','#','X','O','#','X','O','X']
display_board (brd)


If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass the "end" argument to your print statement: print('x', end='')

print() automatically ends with a newline character. Consequently you want to change that to end='' (empty string) for the lines where you don't want a newline.
Furthermore your print('\n') does a double newline, because you give one explicitely and it adds one as usual. You probably want just print() there.
In total:
for r in range (0,rows,1):
    for c in range (0,cols,1):
        print(' ' + board[elems-1] + ' |', end='')
        elems = elems -1    
    print()

